# Why don't deleting the current node and point the previous node on the next node?

Tags: c++

> Suppose you have a pointer p to a node in a simply linked list that is
> not on the last node in the list. You have no other pointer to the
> list except the following links in each node. Describe an O(1)
> algorithm that logically removes the value stored in the node pointed
> to by p (suggestion: use the next node).

Solution : The information from the next node is transferred to the current node pointed to by p and the next node is removed from the list.

Why don't deleting the current node and point the previous node on the next node?

Comment: Because it is a singly linked list. Where do you think you will get the pointer to the previous node from? You can do that if you iterate by using a pointer to the pointer from the previous node, and then this becomes a no-brainer. But this is not the situation that's described here.

Answer (score -1):

The proferred "solution" is not the solution that I would use.  I'd do what you're suggesting here.  If this is a bidirectionally-linked list *(the question does not say),* then you simply link-around the node pointed-to by `p` and discard it.

Of course, when the language is "C++," you can also simply use a "stock list-object" from the standard library ... whereas "C" obliges you to do "actual pointer-twiddling."

Comment: The question says it's a simply linked list. It's singly linked. If it were doubly linked, the question wouldn't be worth asking.